# Apple's Healthkit for crossplatform

Tags: cross-platform, healthkit

After a thoroughly research it seems I can't find a way to integrate HealthKit on a cross platform application as it seems it doesn't provide a REST API and the code has to be exclusively written in either objective-c/swift.
Is there something I'm missing? Is there really no way to retrieve the data from healthkit on a cross platform app?

Comment: Where do you want to run your server, where do you want to run your client for the rest api? Are we talking about a html app that should run on iOS devices? For privacy/authorization reasons alone you will have to go native.

Answer (score 0):

You're not missing anything. HealthKit data is stored exclusively on the user's iPhone, not in the cloud accessible from a web service.